# Is it possible to dynamically change the attribute of a form widget at run time

Tags: django, forms, widget

I currently have an object that looks like this

```
class StudentDetails(forms.Form):
    school_name = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))
    student_name= forms.CharField(required=True)
    student_user_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

Now these fields are being prepoulated in a view before being rendered

```
 return render(request, 'manageStudent.html',
                  {'form': StudentDetails(
                      initial={
                          'school_name': rslt[0][1],
                          'student_name': rslt[0][2],
                          'student_user_name': rslt[0][3]
                      })})
```

My question is if it is possible to make `student_user_name` field disabled ? I would like to toggle that field form enabled to disabled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, generally speaking, it is not a good idea to use disabled / readonly fields in a form especially if you really do not want users to mess with the value of those fields.

The safest option is to conditionally delete the form fields in form **init** and instead pass the data into the template from the view itself for printing if you like.

If you do want to go ahead still, make sure to NOT rely on this form field at all, in your view POST processing. Use what you would already know within the view for what the field value should be.

Also keep in mind, there is an important distinction between disabled and readonly form fields. Readonly will pass the value to your POST data whereas disabled will not. Why does it matter ? (since you are not going to use the value anyway, as we talked about).

It does, because of two reasons:

(1) If the form validation fails for some reason, whatever you intended to show in disabled field will vanish, because the return from the POST will not capture that field value.

(2) If the form field is "required" like in your case, it will give you form validation error for that field since the value will not remain in the POST data.

To avoid this you could try capturing the value in a hidden form field and use javascript / jquery to put the value into the field. Below is an example:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(StudentDetails, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if 'initial' in kwargs:
        _student_user_name = str(kwargs.get('initial').get('student_user_name', None))
        if _student_user_name: 
            self.fields['student_user_name'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
            self.fields['student_user_name'].required = False
            self.fields['hidden_student_user_name'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
            self.fields['hidden_student_user_name'].initial = _student_user_name
```

Keep in mind, even though we are storing the student_user_name in hidden form field, hidden form fields can also be tampered with. So do not use the hidden value in views for any actual storing, but only to re-populate a failed submission form display of the disabled form field value for cosmetic purpose only.

So this is how you make sure the initial value you sent for student user name will still show during form failed submission even though the disabled form field value will vanish (that's why we saved it off in that hidden form field):

In the template page where you display the form, put this bit of javascript code in:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
      if ( $('input[name=hidden_student_user_name]').val() ) {
         var hidden_student_user_name = $('input[name=hidden_student_user_name]').val()
         $('input[name=student_user_name]').prop('disabled', false)
         $('input[name=student_user_name]').val(hidden_student_user_name)
         $('input[name=student_user_name]').prop('disabled', true)
      }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it disabled by setting the `disabled` argument of the field to `True`.

More information here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#disabled

Or to change it while you're on the webpage you can add a checkbox to control the widgets behaviour like this:

In the template you'll have the `input` of the `student_user_name` so all you need to do is add the checkbox button in the form

```
<!-- Input of the 'student_user_name' will be already there if you use {{ form }}-->
<!-- <input type="text" name="student_user_name" />-->
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
```

And in the JavaScript file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checkbox").change(function(){
        if (this.checked){
            $("input[name=student_user_name]").attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $("input[name=student_user_name]").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```